# How to remove part of a name from displaying when a users chooses an item from a drop down list

Tags: javascript

```
sites = [{Code: "YEG", City: "Edmonton", State: "AB", FullSiteName: "AIRPORT_YEG_Edmonton International Airport", Latitude: 53.3097, Longitude: -113.58},
```

I want to just display "*Edmonton International Airport*", instead of "*AIRPORT_YEG_Edmonton International Airport*".

I'm a total newbie, so please be kind...

Thanks

Comment: Are all the locations prefixed with underscores? If that is the case, you could split the name at '_' and just display the last string

Comment: Yes they all have the 'AIRPORT_YEG_' before the part I want to display. How do you display the last string?

Comment: Check out Jeff's answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
var airport = sites.FullSiteName.split("_");
//--- airport[2] contains the full name only
```